# Please help me in pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

I have two gmail accounts and one works perfectly fine.
But the other one give the message of
Our servers are humbled by your incredible response 
We are working on fixing the problem. Please try again soon
And all the servers are up ?

Comment: Multi-accounting is a bannable offense, just for the record.

Comment: Please don't re-ask your question when we close your first one.  If there's an issue, address it.  Asking it again just means we will close the new one, too.

Comment: Pokemon Go is probably down where you live, check [here](http://www.mmoserverstatus.com/pokemon_go)

Comment: Did the closers even read the question?  One of his accounts works perfectly fine, so the problem is NOT with the servers.  The problem is with the account.

Answer (score -4):

You know some people have ddos the game, so the servers are temporaly off, there are no solutions you have to wait.
If you are in the bad country you can't play pokemon go go now. http://www.mmoserverstatus.com/pokemon_go

Comment: How do you know people are DDoSing the game's servers?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eTbJkwSGdzA

Comment: Oh, Poodle. They're a bunch of no-name frauds that just claim fake attacks. They've threatened to bring down my server and absolutely nothing happened.

Comment: Really? So what's actually happened to the servers, a server can't be taken down for no reason. :/

Comment: @Luminos The game is just under a lot of stress from everybody trying to log in and play. Niantic has addressed this, and are working on expanding their server capacity to deal with the load.